# Ruby ActiveRecord multiple joins through associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, associations

I'd like to convert

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `memberships`
    ON `memberships`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `roles`
    ON `roles`.`id` = `memberships`.`role_id`
WHERE `memberships`.`group_id` = 'NUCC' AND (expiration > '2012-07-02')
ORDER BY `roles`.`rank` DESC
```

Into an ActiveRecord association.

Groups have many members (class User) through memberships. Each membership has a role (role_id) which maps to another table (roles) and subsequently an AR model (Role). Each role has a rank (integer) associated with it.

I'd like to simply sort the members of a group by the memberships-roles-rank.

Comment: Note: 'NUCC' needs to come from the Group model itself (the ID of the group) and expiration will be Date.today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, probably has typos, but...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :roles, :through => :memberships, :uniq => true
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships, :uniq => true
end
```

And then, to sort the users by roles.rank:

```
q = User.joins(:memberships => :users)
q = q.where(:memberships.group_id => 'NUCC')
q = q.where("expressionn > '2012-07-02'")
q = q.order("roles.rank DESC")
puts q.to_sql
```

AREL lets you join things up like that pretty easily. For instance, you can keep that going with even further `INNER JOINS` with syntax similar to:

```
User.joins(:memberships => { :users => :someothermodel })
```

Just remember to replicate that structure whenever you need to reference something through the JOIN, or just write your own SQL fragment..

Comment: Thanks for the response! I haven't tried it yet (I will soon/maybe after I post this), however I have a clarifying question;

By specifying :uniq => true, is that limiting a user (member) to one role per group? The model I eventually would like to expand to is that a user can have multiple roles within the group. Not **super** critical atm, but if not difficult, I'd like to leave room for it.

Comment: that is limiting the member to one membership (reference) to *each* role. That is, it protects you from referencing the same Role twice, even if multiple memberships point to it [which you probably don't want to d anyway, but rails will just recognize that "two" roles retried indirectly are actually the same thing and act accordingly. And yes, it's entirely optional, depending on what you need. I just find int useful with "has_many :thoguht => ... " and add it most of the time.